# Ubuntu 12.10, I installed seahorse utils for encryption, but now 'Passwords And Keys' won't open

Tags: password, encryption, seahorse

Ubuntu 12.10, I can open 'Passwords And Keys' app, but then when I install the seahorse plugins, I can no longer open 'Passwords And Keys' -- when I click on the menu item/icon, nothing happens. Then if I uninstall seahorse utils, I can open 'Passwords And Keys' again. Ugh. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/1154049

I'm having the same problem and it's really frustrating.  According to the bug report this issue has been fixed in Seahorse itself but I don't know when the fix will propagate to 12.10.  Apparently the fix also requires a fix in gnome 3.6 too:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694053